# HttpClient POST to WEB API method returns 405 (Method not allowed)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Following request works perfectly when using Postman (Browser) within IIS Express and VS 2015 in a Debug Session:

```
POST http://localhost:51072/api/cs/processor/process

{
'code':'TEST',
  'mode':0
}
```

This is my web api controller method

```
[RoutePrefix("api/cs")]
public class ProcessorController : UmbracoApiController
{...

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("processor/process")]
[HttpPost()]
public IHttpActionResult Process([FromBody] ProcessSurvey dto)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Not allowed to start survey from remote host.");
    }
    ProcessSurveyResponse resp = new ProcessSurveyResponse();
    switch (dto.Code)
    {
        case "ITS":
            resp = Execute(dto.Mode);
            break;
        default:
            resp.Message = "Test successful!";
            break;
    }
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, resp);
}
```

Although when I try to access this method with the exact same request data it returns a 405. After digging deeper I've found that internally it's done a redirect (302). But cannot find any information about what's going on and why in the IIS logs.

What I've done so far is WebDAV removed, Attribute is Http not Mvc, all constellations of route config (belkow is my current one)

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiFull",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and this is my init method

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); //WebApi 2 Register method
```

Really do not know what to do ... struggling for 2 days now and I have no idea where to look further.

Here is the HttpClient call

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                log.Debug("Call " + baseUrl);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:51072/api/cs/surveyprocessor/process/", content);
                string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProcessSurveyResponse>(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Message = data;
                }
                return result;
            }
```

And here is my DTO

```
public class ProcessSurvey
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mode")]
    public int Mode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "customers")]
    public IList<int> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

What's interesting that when I POST over the HttpClient it seems that it does not reach the WebApi module ...

> ```
> > iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET,
> > Url=http://localhost:51072/api/cs/surveyprocessor/process/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1,
> > Message='http://localhost:51072/api/cs/surveyprocessor/process/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1'
> > iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='SurveyProcessor',
> > Operation=NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
> > iisexpress.exe Information: 0 :
> > Message='SSI.CSS.Serviceportal.CS.Controller.SurveyProcessorController',
> > Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create iisexpress.exe
> > Information: 0 :
> > Message='SSI.CSS.Serviceportal.CS.Controller.SurveyProcessorController',
> > Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController iisexpress.exe
> > Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter'
> > formatter',
> > Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
> > iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected
> > formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json;
> > charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
> > iisexpress.exe Warning: 0 : Message='UserMessage='The requested
> > resource does not support http method 'GET'.'',
> > Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction, Status=405
> > (MethodNotAllowed), Exception=System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException:
> > Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
> > the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
> > exception for details.    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
> > controllerContext)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
> > controllerContext)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter
> > traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel
> > level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace,
> > Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) iisexpress.exe
> > Warning: 0 : Message='UserMessage='The requested resource does not
> > support http method 'GET'.'',
> > Operation=SurveyProcessorController.ExecuteAsync, Status=405
> > (MethodNotAllowed), Exception=System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException:
> > Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
> > the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
> > exception for details.    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
> > controllerContext)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
> > controllerContext)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter
> > traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel
> > level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace,
> > Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext
> > controllerContext)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
> > controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
> > --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei
> > System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> > task)    bei
> > System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> > task)    bei
> > System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
> > iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=405
> > (MethodNotAllowed), Method=GET,
> > Url=http://localhost:51072/api/cs/surveyprocessor/process/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1,
> > Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8',
> > content-length=unknown' iisexpress.exe Information: 0 :
> > Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync iisexpress.exe
> > Information: 0 : Operation=SurveyProcessorController.Dispose
> > 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> > /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131394088034503203): Loaded
> > 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> > Files\root\4650863f\f01d951b\App_Web_ping.aspx.5f2dec3.f9ui73ad.dll'. 
> > The thread 0x2830 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x3f10 has
> > exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x2104 has exited with code 0
> > (0x0).
> ```

Comment: How do you `try to access this method with the exact same request data` when it returns a 405? That part is not clear. Show how http client in a [mcve] can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: I see `surveyprocessor` in the called URL but `processor` in the controller code. Is that a typo? or are you calling the wrong URL?

Comment: sorry, typo ... I wanted it to shorten first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed cookieless="AutoDetect" in FormsAuth and SessionProvider module to **cookieless="UseCookies"** and everything works like expected.